# textBox onBlur to call server method instead of client method

Tags: asp.net

I'm extending a web control. I need to call server methods on every event fired by the control instead of javascript.

```
public partial class MyTextBox : RadTextBox, IScriptControl
{
    public MyTextBox()
    {
        Attributes.Add("onBlur", "handleLostFocus();");
        Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
    }

    public void handleLostFocus()
    {
        MyObject obj = new MyObject();
        obj.someproperty = this.Text; //or somehow get the user entered text.

        MyService1 service = new MyService1();
        service.sendRequest(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: And the question you are asking? What is it exactly you need, to do a post back when you lose focus on the textbox?

Comment: Yes, exactly. So, you are saying if I set AutoPostBack = true, it would work?

Comment: By deafult, the TextBox control will post to the server if AutoPostBack is set to true, it loses focus AND a change has ocurred in the textbox itself.

Comment: You are right, it goes to textbox_TextChanged on the server, but it gets fired many times and finally crashes with this error message.
Microsoft JScript runtime error: The value of the property 'handleLostFocus' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, TextBox will post by default if `AutoPostBack = "True"`, however, you need to handle your event. Supposing your TextBox is named TextBox1:

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = TextBox1.Text;
}
```

Get rid of `handleLostFocus()` or have it be the handler for your TextBox control.

Good luck mate.